CSS Grid / Flexbox help
Помогите пожалуйста сделать такой адаптивный макет, чтобы вне зависимости от разрешения 1024х768 или 1920х1080 он оставался таким же


А что значит "height: 70%" для "футера", как такое возможно?

Вместо vh скорее всего придется где-то использовать vw.


* { padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body { height: 100%; }

.wrapper
{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5vh 10vh;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 70vh 1fr;
  gap: 5vh;
}

.main, .footer
{
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.main
{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <main class="main">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque odio placeat reprehenderit unde, enim autem modi quibusdam eum molestias nam quia, mollitia voluptatibus maxime incidunt velit dignissimos a voluptatum aspernatur laborum alias quas id possimus amet? Cum fugiat corporis exercitationem incidunt numquam aliquam delectus magnam possimus quos fuga, eaque molestias esse. Architecto rem corporis, nostrum impedit voluptatibus provident quia aperiam sit, rerum, maxime possimus laboriosam odio? Quo, molestias nostrum. Incidunt laboriosam voluptates vitae! Reiciendis aspernatur similique explicabo, sequi voluptates ex eligendi iusto! Aut assumenda harum et ab fugit quaerat dolorum ipsam laborum,<br /> recusandae perspiciatis ea quos numquam, fugiat delectus. Ratione laborum similique quo repellat reprehenderit voluptate ab voluptates suscipit quisquam at explicabo magni doloribus, enim aperiam delectus rerum praesentium. Quasi odit porro nostrum. Odio saepe minus eius aut provident nesciunt exercitationem ab, fugiat vel deleniti harum enim nulla? Aliquid ab illum iure et excepturi nisi ullam eveniet adipisci reprehenderit, id impedit corporis nobis asperiores<br /> veniam hic, provident atque, architecto esse repellendus. Illo illum ipsum ea sint dolores ducimus tempora cupiditate unde atque<br /> et vitae voluptatibus inventore, sed necessitatibus placeat animi facilis deserunt aliquam pariatur eos id cumque, minus perspiciatis fugiat? Quidem, quos voluptas! Deleniti, dolores officiis adipisci dolorem quaerat id. Debitis explicabo, impedit delectus rem officiis vero inventore, eius odit beatae error sint natus porro maxime magnam cumque totam quibusdam. Vitae suscipit aperiam explicabo ut, id voluptates soluta dignissimos ipsum beatae eum voluptatibus magni quae sed mollitia harum doloribus culpa, molestias quisquam libero aliquid iste, assumenda tempora quia? Impedit eveniet, fugiat distinctio earum perferendis, laudantium blanditiis explicabo laborum fuga<br /> quisquam corporis sunt veniam reprehenderit eaque minus. Ratione quo accusamus nobis! Quisquam cumque ducimus magni, quidem labore eum reprehenderit dolore asperiores, doloremque enim itaque consectetur consequuntur nulla eveniet in explicabo animi.<br /> Numquam dolore odio nobis perspiciatis illum, reprehenderit dolorum itaque qui cupiditate perferendis velit quibusdam necessitatibus dolor voluptatem nostrum quam cumque ducimus magni, quidem labore eum reprehenderit dolore asperiores, doloremque enim itaque consectetur consequuntur nulla eveniet in explicabo animi. Numquam dolore odio nobis perspiciatis illum, reprehenderit dolorum itaque qui cupiditate perferendis velit quibusdam necessitatibus dolor voluptatem nostrum quos blanditiis deleniti ex ipsa. Velit facilis deserunt maxime, esse eaque quae. Eaque quas nulla possimus maxime, unde in voluptas,<br /> aliquid impedit vel libero quod rovident doloremque<br /> atque natus vero eveniet. Quis sequi ipsa eveniet enim nulla qui at omnis saepe? Ea amet id dolorum et tenetur<br /> perspiciatis beatae, provident harum nobis impedit ullam voluptates nulla magnam fuga eligendi veritatis cupiditate accusamus adipisci qui sunt aliquam laboriosam? Eos saepe nesciunt aspernatur, sequi, magnam quia quod facere nulla dolorem ducimus suscipit esse blanditiis commodi<br /> doloribus mollitia unde, quaerat a odio tenetur. Dignissimos tempora vitae ipsa magnam fugiat. Optio velit nobis error earum aperiam quos nam ducimus exercitationem asperiores. Sit voluptate totam quasi perferendis eligendi quidem, voluptatem quae error sunt distinctio reprehenderit minima dignissimos cumque facere aspernatur assumenda ratione soluta accusamus illo voluptatum! Commodi consequatur quod id esse amet quos incidunt eveniet nihil. Dolores voluptatum iste nesciunt. Expedita, facilis perspiciatis ut sit error unde maiores natus quos molestiae aut ad! Necessitatibus harum quos iusto vitae, voluptatem, porro exercitationem unde possimus reiciendis modi reprehenderit voluptatum itaque, quia qui! Praesentium facilis ipsum sint officia, fugiat nam, numquam blanditiis fugit reprehenderit explicabo culpa quia. Incidunt, labore iusto? harum et ab fugit quaerat dolorum ipsam laborum,<br /> recusandae perspiciatis ea quos numquam, fugiat delectus. Ratione laborum similique quo repellat reprehenderit voluptate ab voluptates suscipit quisquam at explicabo magni doloribus, enim aperiam delectus rerum praesentium. Quasi odit porro nostrum. Odio saepe minus eius aut provident nesciunt exercitationem ab, fugiat vel deleniti harum enim nulla? Aliquid ab illum iure et excepturi nisi ullam eveniet adipisci reprehenderit, id impedit corporis nobis asperiores<br /> veniam hic, provident atque, architecto esse repellendus. Illo illum ipsum ea sint dolores ducimus tempora cupiditate unde atque<br /> et vitae voluptatibus inventore, sed necessitatibus placeat animi facilis deserunt aliquam pariatur eos id cumque, minus perspiciatis fugiat? Quidem, quos voluptas! Deleniti, dolores officiis adipisci dolorem quaerat id. Debitis explicabo, impedit delectus rem officiis vero inventore, eius odit beatae error sint natus porro maxime magnam cumque totam quibusdam. Vitae suscipit aperiam explicabo ut, id voluptates soluta dignissimos ipsum beatae eum voluptatibus magni quae sed mollitia harum doloribus culpa, molestias quisquam libero aliquid iste, assumenda tempora quia? Impedit eveniet, fugiat distinctio earum perferendis, laudantium blanditiis explicabo laborum fuga<br /> quisquam corporis sunt veniam reprehenderit eaque minus. Ratione quo accusamus nobis! Quisquam cumque ducimus magni, quidem labore eum reprehenderit dolore asperiores, doloremque enim itaque consectetur consequuntur nulla eveniet in explicabo animi.<br /> Numquam dolore odio nobis perspiciatis illum, reprehenderit dolorum itaque qui cupiditate perferendis velit quibusdam necessitatibus dolor voluptatem nostrum quam cumque ducimus magni, quidem labore eum reprehenderit dolore asperiores, doloremque enim itaque consectetur consequuntur nulla eveniet in explicabo animi. Numquam dolore odio nobis perspiciatis illum, reprehenderit dolorum itaque qui cupiditate perferendis velit quibusdam necessitatibus dolor voluptatem nostrum quos blanditiis deleniti ex ipsa. Velit facilis deserunt maxime, esse eaque quae. Eaque quas nulla possimus maxime, unde in voluptas,<br />
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</div>




Спасибо, то что нужно
